# Algorithm to generate random points on n-Sphere?

Tags: geometry

I know this question already asked and actually well explained in those answers, just one thing that actually confuses be in other answers what if i want to generate random points on the surface of n-Sphere with radius r uniformly?

As according to one of the algorithm, generate n-dimensional vector $[x_1,x_2,..,x_n]$, where $x_i$ is random numbers using Normal Distribution N(0,1) and then use following formula to generate random point on the surface of n-Sphere

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+... +x_n^2}}[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$$

I presume that this will generate random points uniformly on the surface of unit n-Sphere, so what if we want generate random points on the surface n-Sphere with arbitrary radius r do we need to change the variance in Normal distribution or what?

Please forgive me if its a stupid question.

Regards
Ahsan

Comment: Just multiply the whole vector by $r$.

Comment: Can u elaborate a bit please?

Comment: Take the random vector on the unit $n$-sphere, $\frac1{\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, and multiply it by $r$.

Comment: Rahul is right.  $\frac{r}{\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is a random vector on the $n$-sphere with radius $r$.

Comment: Please link the relevant related questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839037/algorithm-to-generate-random-points-in-n-sphere#comment1731602_839037) by [Rahul](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/856/rahul):

> Take the random vector on the unit $n$-sphere, 
>   $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}}[x_1,...,x_n]$$
>   and multiply it by $r$.